# I can't fetch WooCommerce products by category id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I am trying to fetch products by category ID this way:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cat' => $cat_id
); 

$query = new WP_Query($args);

$posts = get_posts($args);
var_dump($posts);

?>
```

The `$cat_id` variable contains the correct category ID. I've checked it. Products are added to correct categories.

The problem is, whenever I `var_dump` the `$posts` variable I get an empty array. As soon as I remove the `'cat'` keyword from the arguments I can fetch products from all categories with no problems. The only problem is the `'cat'` keyword.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this instead:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' = array(
         'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
         'field'    => 'term_id',
         'term'     =>  $cat_id
     )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($query);
```

I haven't test it, but it should work.

Comment: Hey, yes, I managed to test it a few minutes ago, it works (but I had to change 'id' to 'term_id'). I am selecting this answer as correct.